# Starting Apache2 ... fail because -> Another web server is already runing, Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apache2, php, lamp, xampp

I have looked almost everywhere and tried all the solution available on the internet but the apache is not runing. i stoped the apache service using

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```

and also stopped xampp using

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop
```

and then i restarted it but the apache still failed to run. 
I have also looked at the ports by runing

```
sudo netstat -pnltu
```

and the result is

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1223/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21923/systemd-resol 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24042/cupsd         
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1223/nginx: master  
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      24042/cupsd         
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:48407           0.0.0.0:*                           977/avahi-daemon: r 
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           21923/systemd-resol 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           1221/dhclient       
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                           24043/cups-browsed  
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           977/avahi-daemon: r 
udp6       0      0 :::32781                :::*                                977/avahi-daemon: r 
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                977/avahi-daemon: r
```

i also used this command

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

and it says :

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Need the solution asap, its my first internship on monday 13th january 2019 and i dont want to install windows :/..

Ubuntu 18.04
Php 7.2.13
XAMPP for Linux 7.2.13-0...

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have another web server running, namely `nginx`:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1223/nginx: master  
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1223/nginx: master
```

If you stop it using `sudo systemctl stop nginx.service`, you should be able to start Apache.

Comment: ... or change the port of one of them from 80 to something different.

Comment: thanks, i had to kill service runing on port 80 and then restarted lamp... Now the apache service is runing..